# Access to osgi bundle resources

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, bundle

I have an osgi bundle that gets activated when I start my application. I only need to use it from time to time, but I need the bundle to maintain its state (its variables should stay with the same value). But I have been unable to do this: each time the handler gets activated, I have to initialize the bundle's variables again.

Can someone explain how this is done?

Answer (score 2):

Each time a bundle started, a new instance of the BundleActivator is created and called at the start method. It you need to preserve state across multiple bundle starts, you will need to persist your state so that upon each start, you can restore the state. There are of course many many ways to persist data.

Comment: The bundle always maintains its activated state, and from time to time I need to invoke a method from it. The problem is that I don't know about a way to access the bundle without initialising the bundle's class in the handler, each time I need to use it.

Comment: I suggest your bundle register a service that other bundles can obtain and call when they need to communicate with the bundle.